# Issue with unity axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wrote the code, when i getting down keycode "W" my player needs to move forward, but he moves left, and the similar to other key codes. Also speed is to much lower than need, tried another code, all was ok with speed, but not with axis.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
 Rigidbody rb;
 public float moveSpeed;
 
 void Start()
 {
     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
 }

 void Update()
 {
      float horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      float verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
      Vector3 playerMove = new Vector3(horizontalMove, 0.0f, verticalMove);
      playerMove.Normalize();
      rb.AddForce(playerMove*moveSpeed);
 }
```

}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Rigidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) receives the force argument in the world coordinates or the world space, which is not the one you would like to apply the movement in. That is the player's local space.
To make that work, I would transform that local movement you want to apply to the world space with [Transform.InverseTransformDirection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html).

Did not try it, but I think it should work.

```
void Update()
{
     float horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
     float verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
     //Vector3 playerMove = new Vector3(horizontalMove, 0.0f, verticalMove);
     Vector3 worldDirPlayerMove = transform.InverseTransformDirection(horizontalMove, 0.0f, verticalMove);
     worldDirPlayerMove .Normalize();
     rb.AddForce(worldDirPlayerMove *moveSpeed);
}
```

Comment: Sadly but it didn't help... I have the same issue, that keys do not match the directions to move...